# appending to an array within an array in php over ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a stack of php code along these lines:

```
$section1 = 0;
if($input_1_1 == NULL) {
    $report_doCheck_app['errorText_1_1'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
    $report_doCheck_app['resultImg_1_1'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    $report_doCheck_app['checkReport'] = "Section 1, part 1.1 requires correcting<br>";
    $section1 = 1;
} else {
    $report_doCheck_app['resultImg_1_1'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
}

if($input_1_2 == NULL) {
    $report_doCheck_app['errorText_1_2'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
    $report_doCheck_app['resultImg_1_2'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    $report_doCheck_app['checkReport'] = "Section 1, part 1.2 requires correcting<br>";
    $section1 = 1;
} else {
    $report_doCheck_app['resultImg_1_2'] = "<img src=\"./gfx/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
}
```

And so on. The idea being that this is a final form check prior to submission, they user hits a button which triggers an ajax call to the above php, which checks the data that has been entered (by ajax) into the database via the form. If any sections are empty (NULL as determined by the db - nothing is just blank) then I want to highlight the area that needs attention and I need to compile a list to show by the button they pressed to tell them where they need to fix stuff. The list is defined in each iteration of the check - for each item but I think I am not appending the last item to the list that comes up as NULL, to the previous item. For example lets say that **both** the database fields relevant to the code I've shown, are NULL. I will get this as an echo:

```
Section 1, part 1.2 requires correcting<br>
```

When what I should be getting is

```
Section 1, part 1.1 requires correcting<br>
Section 1, part 1.2 requires correcting<br>
```

Etc. Clearly my attempt to append date to the $report_doCheck_app['checkReport'] section is failing. How do I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the value in `$report_doCheck_app['checkReport']` in each section.  Perhaps you mean to concatenate values here?

```
$report_doCheck_app['checkReport'] .= "Section 1, part 1.1 requires correcting<br>";
...
$report_doCheck_app['checkReport'] .= "Section 1, part 1.2 requires correcting<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, that worked perfectly, at least for this particular part of the problem. Appreciated. :)